# Getting "Aborted because 0 is not accepted" and full page reload with react-hot-loader

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, react-hot-loader

I am trying to set up webpack hot reloading with react-hot-loader. It *mostly* seems to be working. I am using webpack in an existing rails app.

But it isn't hot-reloading. It is simply triggering a reload every time my react code is changed. The error messages I get are:

```
[HMR] Cannot apply update. Need to do a full reload! - dev-server.js:18
[HMR] Error: Aborted because 0 is not accepted - dev-server.js:19
  at hotApply (http://localhost:8080/assets/webpack/bundle.js?body=1:380:31)
  at hotUpdateDownloaded (http://localhost:8080/assets/webpack/bundle.js?body=1:293:13)
  at hotAddUpdateChunk (http://localhost:8080/assets/webpack/bundle.js?body=1:273:13)
  at webpackHotUpdateCallback (http://localhost:8080/assets/webpack/bundle.js?body=1:5:12)
  at http://localhost:8080/assets/webpack0.bd89931b2fa8e2901794.hot-update.js:1:1

Navigated to http://lvh.me:3000/react_page
```

Here is my webpack.hot.config.js settings:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var config = module.exports = {

    // Set 'context' for Rails Asset Pipeline
    context: __dirname,

    entry: {
        App: [
            'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080/', // WebpackDevServer host and port
            'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', // "only" prevents reload on syntax errors
            './app/frontend/javascripts/app.js' // Your appʼs entry point
        ],
        vendor: ['jquery', 'react', 'react-dom', 'react-redux', 'redux','redux-thunk']
    },

    devtool: 'inline-source-map',

    // Require the webpack and react-hot-loader plugins
    plugins: [
        //new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(
        {
            name: 'vendor',
            chunks: [''],
            filename: 'vendor.js',
            minChunks: Infinity
        }),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jquery': 'jquery'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: [
                    'react-hot',
                    'babel?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react'
                ],
                cacheDirectory: true
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'assets', 'javascripts', 'webpack'), // Save to Rails Asset Pipeline
        filename: 'bundle.js', // Will output App_wp_bundle.js
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/assets/webpack',

        //publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/assets/webpack' // Required for webpack-dev-server
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    },

};
```

And I run the code with

```
webpack-dev-server -d --config webpack.hot.config.js --hot --inline
```

The rails development environment serves the webpack files outside the application asset pipeline via the webpack-dev-server because of the following setting in my development.rb file.

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new { |source|
  if source =~ /webpack\/bundle\.js$/i
    "http://localhost:8080"
  end
}
```

I have been trying to get this working for hours. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6):

Ok i was getting the same error, but after trying some things out i figured this out: My root component was a stateless functional component (pure function). I refactored it to a class component and BAM! the hot reloading is working again.

Before:

```
const App = (props) => (
  <div>
    <Header links={headerLinks} logoSrc={logoSrc} />
    {props.children}
  </div>
);
```

After:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header links={headerLinks} logoSrc={logoSrc} />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: a lift saver , do you know why it did that ?

Answer (score 5):

As the answers provided above are still not working on my side with **webpack 5**,
Here is the working config from [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement)

In **webpack.config.js**

```
devServer: {
    .
    .
    .
    hot: true,
  }
```

In the webpack entrypoint **index.js** add

```
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
}
```

In **package.json** start script

```
"scripts": {
    .
    .
    "start": "webpack serve --config /webpack.config.js"
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into this exact issue, the fix for me was removing this from the `entries` array: `'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9000/',`.

As I was also running `--hot` as a command line argument, there were two instances of `webpack-dev-server` getting into a bad state.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will specifically help your issue, but I encountered this error recently as well - i fixed it by adding a `.js` extension to the module I was trying to set up with hmr - here was my code

```
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('app/Routes', () => (
    getRoutes = require('app/Routes')
  ))
}
```

I updated it to `getRoutes = require('app/Routes.js')` and the error disappeared, using `webpack ^2.0.0-beta`.

it also works if i add the JS extension as the first argument of hot accept like so:

```
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('app/Routes.js', () => (
    getRoutes = require('app/Routes')
  ))
}
```

so now it matches whats on the [webpack HMR page](https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement.html)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem. 
After 2 days of research and trying different things, I found out the simplest cause to my problem ever: 
in webpack.config.js, I had a HRM dev server enabled. And I also had a HMR server run from command line. Thanks to hint from [Tyler Kelley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40050967/7449739) (see above), just by removing --hot from command line, it works OK now.

current webpack.config.js

```
devtool: "inline-source-map",
devServer: {
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    port: 9000,
    hot: true
},
```

With this configuration, don't do this:

> ```
> npx webpack-dev-server --hot --inline
> ```

Do this:

`npx webpack-dev-server`

Answer (score 0):

For "webpack": "^5.74.0" and "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1".
I set devServer.static = ['./webpack-dev-server', './dist'], in webpack.config.js.
There is my config:

```
module.exports = {
devtool: 'inline-source-map',
devServer: {
    open: true,
    static: ['./webpack-dev-server', './dist']
},
entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.ts'),
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(ttf|png|svg|jpg|jpeg)$/i,
            type: 'asset/resource',
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        },
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
                configFile: path.join(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json')
            }
        }
    ]
},
mode: 'development',
output: {
    filename: '[name][contenthash].js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true,
},
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html'),
        inject: 'body'
    })
],
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
}
```

}