# Webpack HRM requires a full reload for CSS files

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, webpack, frontend

Webpack HRM works fine with javascript file but doesn't seem to work with CSS files. It requires a full reload and the error below is logged in console:

[HRM]Error: Aborted because ./src/css/my-app/layout/page.css is not accepted
Update propagation:
./src/css/my-app/layout/page.css → ./src/css/root.js → ./src/root. frontend.

Webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');

const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/root.frontend.js',
    target: ['web', 'es5'],
    output: {
        filename: 'my-app.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist.frontend'),
        clean: true
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                styles: {
                    name: "styles",
                    type: "css/mini-extract",
                    chunks: "all",
                    enforce: true,
                },
            },
        },
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                extractComments: false,
                terserOptions: {
                    format: {
                        comments: false
                    }
                }
            }),
            new CssMinimizerPlugin({
                include: "my-app.css"
            })
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "my-app.css",
        }),
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: "src/static", to: ""}
            ]
        })
    ],
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                type: "asset/resource",
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(json)/,
                type: 'asset/resource'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png)/,
                type: 'asset/resource'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: "defaults" }],
                            ['@babel/preset-react', { targets: "defaults" }]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"]
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 7450,
        static: ["testbed"],
        devMiddleware: {
            writeToDisk: true
        },
        setupMiddlewares: (middlewares, devServer) => {
            if (!devServer) {
                throw new Error("webpack-dev-server is not defined");
            }
            devServer.app.post("/post-test", (_, response) => {
                response.redirect("/ajax-test.html");
            });          response.json(result);
            return middlewares;
        }
    }
};
```

Entry imports structure:

```
- root.frontend.js
  - /css/my-app/root.js
    - /css/my-app/layout/page.css
```

Comment: It seems like your file:page.css wasn't included within my-app.css due to the reason it isn't loaded and throws error

Comment: It is included as the page is styled

Comment: Have  your read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35811809/getting-aborted-because-0-is-not-accepted-and-full-page-reload-with-react-hot and https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/